# Android database overWriting same row over and over

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now.
I have an Activity that calls a method to write some values into a database, it works, except for the fact that it overWrites the same row in the database over and over again. My database table does have an _id that is set to autoincrement.

```
try {
    myDataBase.beginTransaction();
    myDataBase.insert("camera_notes", null, camera_data);
    myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
     Log.i(TAG,"#################Exception thrown from updateDataBaseNotes:################ "+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    myDataBase.endTransaction();
}

close();
```

I have just tried adding the transaction code, but no luck so far.
Does anyone have any ideas or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
ContentValues camera_data = new ContentValues();
camera_data.put("note_title", title);
camera_data.put("note_text", note);
camera_data.put("image_source", image_src);
camera_data.put("sound_source", recording_src);
```

Comment: What's in camera_data? You're not accidentally setting the _id in there?

Comment: Hello,I just added camera_data, it is an instance of ContentValues.

Comment: The _id is not being set there.

Comment: How many rows are in the table already? Is that the only one? Is it possible that you're destroying the database before inserting each entry?

Comment: Hi EboMike, it is possible, I'll go through my code again and check, thanks.

Comment: Hi EboMike, had a good hunt around my code, you were right, my db was indeed being destroyed. Solved by adding a global class to hold db state, then checking it to avoid db recreation. I'll add the link to the SO resource I used to help with the class. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables). How do I vote up your answer?

Comment: That was just a comment. I'll write a quick answer your you to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the only row? If so, it sounds like you're destroying the entire table each time before you're inserting the row.